# discord.py put the role id on the name on commands.has_any_role

Tags: discord.py

I would like to replace the role name with the id. I have tried often in recent months but I never succeed.
I would need the IDs because so in case we change the name of the roles I don't have to reprogram everything

```py
@commands.has_any_role('Triumvirato')
```

Comment: You should be able to pass the ids.  Make sure your discord.py is the latest version and make sure you pass the id(s) as ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on developer mode in discord. (User Settings>Appearance>Advanced>Developer Mode: ON). Then go to the roles tab and right-click the role you want to have the ID of, there should be 'Copy ID' and the ID would be copied to the clipboard.

Alternatively, you can access a member's roles `member.roles` it would return a list and you can access the role ID there for example; `member.roles[0].id`.